# RBAC Data Model Design

Tags: database-design, permissions, role, many-to-many

I'm trying to implement roles and permissions for an application I'm working on, from my understanding its an RBAC system.
There are Users, Sites, and for each site a user can have different permissions.

The user - sites relationship is many to many
a user can be a part of many sites
and a site can have many users

A user can have different role with different permissions for each site whether it comes with Admin, Write+Read, Read.

Would creating a 3 way lookup table like this work or what would be a good way to implement this type of system?

[image]

Comment: Look at this requirement and then go back to your diagram: "A user can have different role with different permissions for each site whether it comes with Admin, Write+Read, Read.".

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. 


I’m pretty new to this — I figured that having a table that keeps track of siteid, userid, roleid — then for a current logged in user when they switch to different “sites” I’d get their different permissions. Is there something I’m missing?

Comment: Right now your data model has the following deficiencies: 1. A `User` for an `Org` that doesn't match the `Site` can be assigned a `Role` for that `Site`. 2. A `User` from `RoleAssignment` could differ from the `User` in `UserSiteRole`.  Ditch the `Id` columns, use composite keys, and update your question with your progress if you're still stuck.